# Remote mounting

Tags: unix, mount

```
mount -t smbfs -o username=Administrator,password=Password //severIP/dev/hda1 /mnt/mountTemp
```

where

/dev/hda1 - filesystem in the remote machine

/mnt/mountTemp - mount pont in the local machine

This command mounts a remote filesystem in your local machine. But is there a possibility where you can mount the remote filesystem in the remote machine itself??(but the command has to be fired from your local machine)

Comment: Yes, by using `ssh` to the remote.

Comment: /dev/hda1 sounds like a local filesystem not a remote one. It should be //remostehost/remotesharedir

Comment: Ya...Thats correct..I'll update the question

Comment: @hari: That ability would be a security risk. Imagine, that somebody outside will mount my `/usr/bin` to a remote host... B-r-r.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ssh to run command on remote machine](http://bashcurescancer.com/run_remote_commands_with_ssh.html)

```
ssh user@remote command
```

Comment: if i login to the remote machine and do mounting, it will be as good as mounting locally, on that machine

Comment: yes it's the same as you login via ssh to the remote machine then run the mount command.

Comment: So, the way I've mentioned above is not possible?

Comment: Why dont you want to login/run the mount via ssh? :) Somehow you have to send the command to the remote machine. With ssh it's really easy.