# Connect:Direct From Linux server to Unix

Tags: linux, shell, unix

there are 4 files which will be generated each day in a Linux server. the files has to be sent daily via connect direct to another server which is in unix.

eg..ABC_1JUNE.txt,   BCD_1JUNE.txt,     CDE_1JUNE.txt,    DEF_1JUNE.txt

how to do this in shell script...

Comment: by connect direct do you mean this [ConnectDirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connect:Direct). Why would you not use ssh or mounts as proposed in the answers?

Comment: @1_CR..yes pal...its our requirement where client wants the files sent via Connect:Direct...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To schedule daily jobs on a UNIX-like system you can usually do that with cron. Create a script for that job in the `/etc/cron.daily` directory on the Linux server and have the `cron` daemon run it automatically. The script should simply contain the commands to be run. In this case it could look something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

source=<local-dir>
destination=<remote-server>:<remote-dir>
suffix=1JUNE.txt

for file in {ABC,BCD,CDE,DEF}_${suffix}; do
    scp "$source/$file" "$destination"
done
```

This assumes there is a SSH daemon running on the remote server that you can connect to with `scp`. Replace the values for `source` and `desination` to match your real server name and file structures. The `source` here could also be a remote server.

Answer (score 1):

mount the target server shared folder in the source server folder (or vice versa) and copy the files there using cp command.
For filesystem mount :
    http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl8_mount.htm
    [Remote mounting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401102/remote-mounting)